# How to switch to second scene if button clicked and other conditions met?

Tags: swift, xcode, switch-statement, scene

I'm a newbie at swift and I'm trying to switch to a second scene when the correct email and password have been inputted and the log in button has been pressed in swift.

Here is my code so far:

```
 class FirstScreen: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

     }


     @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var passwordLabel: UITextField!



     @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton)
     {
         let emailLabel1 = emailLabel.text!
         let passwordLabel1 = passwordLabel.text!
         if((emailLabel1.contains("email")) && (passwordLabel1.contains("password")))
         {


         }
         else
         {
             print("ERROR")
         }

     }


 }
```

How would I go about programatically switching to a second scene in the if statement? I'm using xCode 11 and swift 5.1. Any help would be great thanks

Comment: Have a look at [Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html).

Answer (score 2):

- Use storyBoard identifier

updated code is below

```
class FirstScreen: UIViewController {

 @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

 }


 @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var passwordLabel: UITextField!



 @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton)
 {
     let emailLabel1 = emailLabel.text!
     let passwordLabel1 = passwordLabel.text!
     if((emailLabel1.contains("email")) && (passwordLabel1.contains("password")))
     {
         let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
         let secondView =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
         if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
             self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondView, animated: false)
         }else{
             self.present(secondView, animated: true, completion: nil)
         }


     }
     else
     {
         print("ERROR")
     }

 }
```

}